# Data inside tableview are mixed-up after scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

I've read many questions and tried the solutions but I still couldn't resolve the problem with my `tableview`.

After scrolling, the data in the rows of the tableview got interchanged and sometimes missing.

Here's my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *modifierCheckCell = @"BGMModifierCheckCell";

    BGMModifierCheckCell *cell = nil;
    cell = (BGMModifierCheckCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:modifierCheckCell];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray* topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:modifierCheckCell owner:self options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = (BGMModifierCheckCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }


        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        NSArray *optionIds = [[[arrayInsideDict objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"optnItem"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        BGMOptnCats *optnCat = [BGMOptnCats MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"iOptnCatId" withValue:[[arrayInsideDict objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"optnCatId"]];

        [optionIds enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

            __block int optnTag = [obj intValue];

            BGMItemDayOptns *item = [BGMItemDayOptns MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"iItemDayOptnId" withValue:obj];

            [item.optns.optnLangs enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, BOOL *stop) {

                BGMOptnLangs *lang = (BGMOptnLangs *)obj;

                if ([lang.sLangCode isEqualToString:@"en"]) {

                    NSString *optn = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", lang.sOptnName];

                    if ([optnCat.sOptnType isEqualToString:@"single"]) {

                        RadioButton *rb1                   = [[RadioButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 40)];
                        [rb1 setGroupID:indexPath.section AndID:optnTag AndTitle:optn];
                        rb1.delegate                    = self;

                        if (idx == 0) {

                            [cell.firstOption addSubview:rb1];

                        } else if (idx == 1) {

                            [cell.secondOption addSubview:rb1];

                        } else if (idx == 2) {

                            [cell.thirdOption addSubview:rb1];

                        }


                    } else if ([optnCat.sOptnType isEqualToString:@"multiple"]) {

                        SSCheckBoxView *checkBox = [[SSCheckBoxView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 40) style:kSSCheckBoxViewStyleMono checked:NO];
                        checkBox.tag = optnTag;
                        [checkBox setStateChangedTarget:self selector:@selector(checkBoxViewChangedState:)];
                        [checkBox setText:@""];
                        [checkBox setText:optn];

                        if (idx == 0) {

                            [cell.firstOption addSubview:checkBox];

                        } else if (idx == 1) {

                            [cell.secondOption addSubview:checkBox];

                        } else if (idx == 2) {

                            [cell.thirdOption addSubview:checkBox];

                        }


                    }

                }

            }];

        }];

    }

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: I don't know if this will help, since you said in your comment below that you've tried moving the code outside the if cell == nil block, but you shouldn't use that if clause at all. You should register your nib (in viewDidLoad) using registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:, and then delete the if cell==nil clause, because the cell will never be nil when you do it that way.

Comment: @rdelmar, I've resolved the problem by commenting out the if (cell ==nil). But I didn't remove the codes inside the if statement. I didn't add registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: inside the viewDidLoad,  may I know why this is necessary?

Comment: That is the new, and I think more efficient way to load a nib based cell. You don't have to use it, but by taking out the if cell==nil clause and leaving in the nib loading code, you may be loading the nib many times (I don't know if there's any optimization the the system does to prevent that).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your cells are being reused. So the rows are interchanged when scrolling.

Set the cell content outside of the if (cell == nil).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *modifierCheckCell = @"BGMModifierCheckCell";

    BGMModifierCheckCell *cell = nil;
    cell = (BGMModifierCheckCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:modifierCheckCell];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray* topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:modifierCheckCell owner:self options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = (BGMModifierCheckCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
     }


        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        NSArray *optionIds = [[[arrayInsideDict objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"optnItem"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        BGMOptnCats *optnCat = [BGMOptnCats MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"iOptnCatId" withValue:[[arrayInsideDict objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"optnCatId"]];

        [optionIds enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

            __block int optnTag = [obj intValue];

            BGMItemDayOptns *item = [BGMItemDayOptns MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"iItemDayOptnId" withValue:obj];

            [item.optns.optnLangs enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, BOOL *stop) {

                BGMOptnLangs *lang = (BGMOptnLangs *)obj;

                if ([lang.sLangCode isEqualToString:@"en"]) {

                    NSString *optn = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", lang.sOptnName];

                    if ([optnCat.sOptnType isEqualToString:@"single"]) {

                        RadioButton *rb1                   = [[RadioButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 40)];
                        [rb1 setGroupID:indexPath.section AndID:optnTag AndTitle:optn];
                        rb1.delegate                    = self;

                        if (idx == 0) {

                            [cell.firstOption addSubview:rb1];

                        } else if (idx == 1) {

                            [cell.secondOption addSubview:rb1];

                        } else if (idx == 2) {

                            [cell.thirdOption addSubview:rb1];

                        }


                    } else if ([optnCat.sOptnType isEqualToString:@"multiple"]) {

                        SSCheckBoxView *checkBox = [[SSCheckBoxView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 40) style:kSSCheckBoxViewStyleMono checked:NO];
                        checkBox.tag = optnTag;
                        [checkBox setStateChangedTarget:self selector:@selector(checkBoxViewChangedState:)];
                        [checkBox setText:@""];
                        [checkBox setText:optn];

                        if (idx == 0) {

                            [cell.firstOption addSubview:checkBox];

                        } else if (idx == 1) {

                            [cell.secondOption addSubview:checkBox];

                        } else if (idx == 2) {

                            [cell.thirdOption addSubview:checkBox];

                        }


                    }

                }

            }];

        }];

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have tried that also and the same problem exist.

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove your subviews because each time CellForRowAtIndexpath is called it will create a subview  so before adding new subview remove the previous one

```
for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
                    [view removeFromSuperview];
                }
```